# difference between aggregate functions in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering why the below query is not retrieving the difference between two aggregate functions(sum) properly ?

```
SELECT 
    epa.status as Status,
    sum(equip_port_usage.total_nbr_ports) as Total,
    sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED) as Used,
    sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED)
      - sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED) as Difference
  FROM site_inst
  INNER JOIN site_attr_settings
     ON site_attr_settings.site_inst_id = site_inst.site_inst_id
  INNER JOIN epa on epa.site_inst_id=site_inst.site_inst_id
  INNER JOIN equip_inst ON equip_inst.site_inst_id=site_inst.site_inst_id
  INNER JOIN equip_port_usage
     ON equip_port_usage.equip_inst_id=equip_inst.equip_inst_id
WHERE site_inst.SITE_HUM_ID = 'CLEUS'
GROUP BY epa.status;
```

The output is like below

```
Ok        303876  10276     0
Faulty     19044    644     0
Reserved   19872    672     0
```

I am expecting it to be

```
Ok        303876  10276  293600
Faulty     19044    644   18400
Reserved   19872    672   19200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a copy and paste failure in your code. 
You're calculating

```
sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED)
 - sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED)
```

which is always 0.

Try:

```
SELECT 
    epa.status as Status,
    sum(equip_port_usage.total_nbr_ports) as Total,
    sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED) as Used,
    sum(equip_port_usage.total_nbr_ports)
     - sum(equip_port_usage.NBR_PORTS_ASSIGNED) as Difference
  FROM site_inst
  INNER JOIN site_attr_settings
     ON site_attr_settings.site_inst_id = site_inst.site_inst_id
  INNER JOIN epa ON epa.site_inst_id=site_inst.site_inst_id
  INNER JOIN equip_inst ON equip_inst.site_inst_id=site_inst.site_inst_id
  INNER JOIN equip_port_usage
     ON equip_port_usage.equip_inst_id=equip_inst.equip_inst_id
 WHERE site_inst.SITE_HUM_ID = 'CLEUS'
 GROUP BY epa.status
```

Answer (score 0):

You're summing the same column twice, and subtracting the two results, so of course you'll always get `0`.

Comment: stupidity of mine...should have checked before posting it :-) thanks for the responses guys anyway